# Commerce 2 Subscriptions (Using Stripe API)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm currently trying to implement and understand how Subscriptions work on Commerce 2. I'm using Stripe API and have created the subscriptions on their CP. I've listed them on my shop page and added the form that goes to "commerce/subscriptions/subscribe".

However, when i click on the submit button, the page is simply reloading itself without any error message. I've tried looking for any _POST response but not are found.

Can anyone tell me the correct flow please? I assume you:

- List the subscriptions
- Submit the subscription with the subscription id (to commerce/subscriptions/subscribe)
- It checks for stored card details and if none found, presents the add card page
- Submits those details and processes returning result

Is that correct?

Really appreciate any help.